# How can I convert an image from raw data in Android without any munging?

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures

I have raw image data (may be .png, .jpg, ...) and I want it converted in Android without changing its pixel depth (bpp). In particular, when I load a grayscale (8 bpp) image that I want to use as alpha (`glTexImage(`) with `GL_ALPHA`), it converts it to 16 bpp (presumably `5_6_5`).

While I do have a plan B (actually, I'm probably on plan 'E' by now, this is really becoming annoying) I would really like to discover an easy way to do this using what is readily available in the API.

So far, I'm using `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()`.

While I'm at it. I'm doing this from a native environment via JNI (passing the buffer in from C, and a new buffer back to C from Java). Any portable solution in C/C++ would be preferable, but I don't want to introduce anything that might break in future versions of Android, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure about the results but you may try to convert all image files into a single format first. then it willl be easier to customize one loading library.

Comment: There is a [question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268659/android-load-image-on-the-native-side) that asks a similar question and there are a couple of solutions posted there. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I can circumvent the problem by "knowing" what the image is and how I want to interpret it. But if Android would just give me the image as it should be, I wouldn't have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that since JPEG images use a Y or YUV colourspace they do not really have a pixel depth and thus there is no "right" depth for them. That said, you are correct in expecting a 8bpp grayscale image when decoding a monochrome JPEG.

I don't know of an available API to achieve what you are trying to do in an automatic way. However, you can ask for a specific depth using the `BitmapFactory` preferred options:

```
 BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
 // This option is suitable for monochrome JPEGs:
 opts.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8;
 // This option is suitable for 32-bit PNGs:
 opts.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_8888;

 bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, len, opts);
```

This is still a hint for the decoder and does not guarantee that you will always get what you expect. I have additional suggestions:

- embed your own versions of libPNG and/or libJPEG. I suggest trying [libjpeg-turbo](http://libjpeg-turbo.virtualgl.org/) which allows to fine-tune the available colourspaces even more.
- instead of using PNG or JPEG as your interchange format, use one or several texture compression formats suitable for your target devices; there are [readily available tools](http://www.androidworks.com/opengl-es2-texture-compression-in-android) to convert PNGs to ETC1, which is part of the OpenGL ES standard. Maybe add a layer of `gzip` on top of that.
- do not hesitate to experiment and try **generic compression methods**: store your image just as you would upload it to the video card, and compress it using `libgz` or `libbzip2`. I have images that get significantly smaller using bzip2 on an uncompressed version than when crushing with [pngcrush](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/). That may be an acceptable tradeoff.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, these are all useful suggestions. I will consider them when I get back around to this issue; however, I am also considering adopting SDL, as it can help me keep my codebase very portable.

Answer (score 0):

To convert raw to image, the best Java API is *ImageIO*.

Documentation: [ImageIO @ Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html)

It may help you.